# Sharepoint: Using custom layout the drag and drop of webpart is not working

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I am having an issue with the drag and drop of webpart in sharepoint. The following described what I have done:

1. I am using MOSS 2007.
2. Created some custom page layouts that's based on the original BlankWebPartPage.aspx and tweaked to matched our HTML carve.
3. Created custom web parts.
4. attached those web parts to the pages that's based on the custom layout.

Now the web parts are working fine, except for the part that it cannot be dragged and drop to other web parts container on the same page.

If anyone can show me:
1. How to diagnose the issue on what's causing it?
2. Is the drag and drop supposed to work on a custom layout?
3. What's the error that's causing it not to work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you be more specific - what exactly happens on the screen? Can you see the title of the web part moving around?

Answer (score 1):

Is this the issue you're experiencing: [http://blog.mastykarz.nl/css-causes-javascript-error-while-moving-web-parts-in-edit-mode](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/css-causes-javascript-error-while-moving-web-parts-in-edit-mode/)/?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah that's the one exactly! There is another link in there:

http://neilmosafi.blogspot.com/2007/11/sharepoint-dragging-webparts-causes.html

That link shows a javascript to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You might try dragging into the "add web part" portion of the container of zone. I've had issues with dragging the web parts into position, particularly custom web parts.

Also, can you post some code? Particularly the page layout. Feel free to clip out the most non-essential parts, but it should help to diagnose your problem.

Comment: Hi Stefan, 
The following is the zonetemplate code. Let me know if you need anything else.

<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" AllowPersonalization="false" ID="VecciMainContentTop" FrameType="None" Title="Main Content Top" Orientation="Vertical">
        <ZoneTemplate>
        </ZoneTemplate>
    </WebPartPages:WebPartZone>